# Axios upload jpg in form data format, response data: { error: 'Multipart: Boundary not found' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, postman, multipartform-data

I want to upload a jpg to a link with axios but failed. 
I doubt that is there sth wrong with my form data, I dont know how to check that.
I do it in this way:

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('screenshot',fs.createReadStream(`xxx.jpg`));
```

screenshot is the key while the next one is the jpg that I want to post.
Here is my post method:

```
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
yield axios.post(url,form,config).then....catch....
```

I have successfully upload the jpg through postman:
[image]

How can I do the same thing with NodeJS in VScode?
The error message is very long but main pt. should be response data: { error: 'Multipart: Boundary not found' }.

Here is some content in sever:

```
const upload = multer({
//dest: 'screenshots',
limits: {
    fileSize: 2000000 //number in bytes
},
fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('File must be of png/jpg/jpeg type.'))
    }
    cb(undefined, true)
}

router.post('/upload/:id/screenshot', findCasebyID, upload.single('screenshot'), async (req, res) => {
try {
        req.case.screenshot = req.file.buffer
        await req.case.save()
        res.send()
} catch (e) {
    res.status(409).send(e)
}...
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it with this:

```
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`, } };
```

Comment: Thank you. Had exactly the same problem when migrating from request to axios. It seems request sets the boundary automatically, while for axios you have to add the header manually.